# .net5 API File Upload corrupting file

Tags: c#, rest, .net-5

I'm trying to make a document upload method for our API. Text files upload fine but word documents, pdfs, images all end up corrupted. If I try to upload a 18kb image file it saves in the correct location with the correct filename and extension but it suddenly is a 31kb file that can't be opened.

```
**Controller Method**
[HttpPost("{uid}/Document")]
public IActionResult SaveDocument(int uid, [FromForm] Document document)
{
    _entityService.SaveDocument(uid, UserUID, document);
    return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status201Created);
}

**Service Method**
public async void SaveDocument(int uid, int userUID, Document document)
{
    try
    {
        string path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Temp", document.FileName);

        using (FileStream createStream = new(path, FileMode.Create))
            await document.FormFile.CopyToAsync(createStream);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        EventLogger.LogException(ex);
        throw;
    }
}

**Model**
public class Document
{
    public IFormFile FormFile { get; set; }
    public byte[] bytes { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70103072/9925593)

Comment: @Pato not sure what you wanted me to see there. Fairly certain it's not a problem with filesize as the files I'm testing with are well under 100kb.

Comment: Sorry my bad. Can you share your post request? your method seems to be okay

Comment: I'm posting via Postman. 
POST, form-data, adding the file via Value column. One of my other teammates setup a React page to post and we're getting the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with .net6.

Uploading 67kb file using postman, I can see in wireshark that its always sending the file correctly, first thing that i'm doing in controller is to save the file locally. After 66 tries I got following file sizes: 2x 64kb, 37x 67kb, 3x 71kb,18x 79kb, 6x 83kb.

What turned out to be the issue was the middleware, I didn't await the `_next(httpContext)` so when I read the body and modified `Body.Position` after calling `_next`, I messed with the reading process in the controller.

Apparently when I got an exception saying "The inner stream position has changed unexpectedly." I should have listened to that more carefully :p

Answer (score 0):

Some possible causes:

1. You could have an antivirus/malware/IDS doing something in the background.
2. Your file is getting messed up when you try to transport or convert. You can check if IFormFile interface is casting correctly.

I've tested your methods and everything works with IFormFile as the argument.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
// ...
[HttpPost("tester")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> Tester(IFormFile file)
{

  Document document = new() {
    FormFile = file,
    FileName = file.FileName,
    ContentType = file.ContentType,
  };

  string path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Temp", document.FileName);

  using (FileStream createStream = new(path, FileMode.Create))
    await document.FormFile.CopyToAsync(createStream);

  return Ok(new { success = true, message = "All set", file });
}
```

Request and result:

[image]

Comment: So I tried the changes you made to the method and I'm seeing the same result as before. Any thoughts as to what I could try next, or ways I could test for the possible issues you listed?