# Program crashed when trying to post a View Model which has IFormFile file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm trying to create a model that has a File (image) but the program keep crashing when POST. Therefore I don't know where to put a breakpoint for debugging when it crashes like that.

This is my View Model `CreateNovelViewModel.cs`:

```
public class CreateNovelViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        public String NovelTitle { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public String NovelDescription { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public IFormFile NovelCover { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string UserID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int AuthorID { get; set; }
    }
```

`NovelsController.cs`:

```
// GET: Novels/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.AuthorId = new SelectList(_context.Authors, "AuthorId", "AuthorName");
            ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(_context.Users, "UserId", "UserId");
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Novels/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CreateNovelViewModel novelVM)
        {
            Novel novel = new Novel();
            try
            { 
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    byte[] uploadedFile = new byte[novelVM.NovelCover.Length];
                    novel.NovelTitle = novelVM.NovelTitle;
                    //novel.NovelCover = novelVM.NovelCover;
                    novel.NovelDescription = novelVM.NovelDescription;
                    novel.AuthorId = novelVM.AuthorID;
                    novel.UserId = novelVM.UserID;
                    _context.Add(novel);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Không thể thêm.Hãy thử lại, nếu vấn đề còn tồn tại, liên hệ người có chuyên môn.");
                }
            }
            catch (RetryLimitExceededException ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Không thể thêm. Hãy thử lại, nếu vấn đề còn tồn tại, liên hệ người có chuyên môn.");
            }
            ViewData["AuthorId"] = new SelectList(_context.Authors, "AuthorId", "AuthorName", novelVM.AuthorID);
            ViewData["UserId"] = new SelectList(_context.Users, "UserId", "UserId", novelVM.UserID);
            return View(novel);
        }
```

`Create.cshtml`:

```
@model WebNovel.Models.ViewModels.CreateNovelViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Novel</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 p-3">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="NovelTitle" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="NovelTitle" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="NovelTitle" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="NovelDescription" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="NovelDescription" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="NovelDescription" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="NovelCover" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="NovelCover" type="file" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="NovelCover" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="AuthorID" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="AuthorID" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.AuthorId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="UserID" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="UserID" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.UserId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

The program crashes whenever I try to hit Create button. I suspect it got some kind of error in the View Model.

Edit: It shows the error:

[image]

In terminal: `The program '[8] WebNovel.exe' has exited with code 4294967295 (0xffffffff).`

So far I've tried:

- Change port number
- Delete `applicationhost.config` in my project
- Update/reinstall VS2022
- Upload a smaller file, one is image (~9.8KB), one is a text file (9B)
- Increasing file size limit

None of them fix my problem.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Stupid answer, but are you sure to execute your web app with compilation mode debug?
Also, CTRL+ALT+E and enable all "Common language runtime exception"

This helped you?

Comment: I don't know how to enable compilation mode debug. I run my app with debugging (F5) all the time. I enabled all "Common language runtime exception" like you said but there is nothing shows.

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint and stepped through your code?

Comment: @Marco Everytime I click the Create button to submit the form, program crashes. I put a breakpoint right under the [HttpPost] `Create` action but it didn't even step into it.

Comment: @pilog try also to delete .vs folder and .suo file ...

Answer (score 1):

despite the error , what i noticed that you missed to add {enctype="multipart/form-data"} to your form,

```
<form asp-action="Create" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
```

so now the form will carry files with him.

Comment: Thanks, I added it but nothing change. It still crashes whenever I do [HttpPost] `Create` action.

Comment: okay , if you add a brake point in the post create ,it will enter it or it will crash in the front end only with out goinig to the back end ?

Comment: I think it crashes in the front end because  I add a break point at the [HttpPost] `Create` action, it crashes before hit the break point.

Comment: okay then try to add asp-controller="your controller name"  before asp-action="Create" in the form tag

Comment: if not working ,then if i were you ,i will rescafold the view of the create method

Comment: It still not work. I tested putting a `String` instead of `IFormFile` in View Model `CreateNovelViewModel.cs` before, it works, the posted View Model has its valid values. But since I changed the attribute to `IFormFile`, the error occurs. I don't know why.

Comment: i suspect of this {byte[] uploadedFile = new byte[novelVM.NovelCover.Length];}

Comment: It crashes before the [HttpPost] `Create` action get any values of the View Model. I put a break points inside the action, program didn't hit any break point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252665/discussion-between-pilog-and-khaled-helwane).

Answer (score 1):

The disk and memory used by file uploads depend on the number and size of concurrent file uploads. If an app attempts to buffer too many uploads, the site crashes when it runs out of memory or disk space. You can try to test with a smaller file to see if it works.

If you really have a problem with too large files, you can add the following attributes to the action:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[DisableRequestSizeLimit]
[RequestFormLimits(ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue, MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CreateNovelViewModel novelVM)
{
}
```

Helpful links:

[File upload scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-7.0#file-upload-scenarios).

[ASP.NET Core web application - How to upload large files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70102558/asp-net-core-web-application-how-to-upload-large-files).

Comment: Thanks, I tried a file with smaller size (~13.4KB) but the problem isn't fixed. Even when I added 2 notations you suggested. Somehow I cannot Post a `IFormFile` type, because I Posted a String type before and it works normally.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the solution but, since you have two actions with the same name ("Create"), you should specify [HttpGet] in the first action as you did with the second one where you set [HttpPost]. This should help ASP.NET to bind the actions.

Comment: Thanks, it helps my code become more readable but the problem hasn't solved.